# When there is no Javascript turned on. What other solution?

Tags: css, javascript

I am working on a website. I have an image that I set to `display: none` in CSS. I used JavaScript to display it and slide it in after page has finished loading. It's working perfectly.

I want to launch the website, with JS disabled and see what will happen. I reloaded the web page, and the image didn't show at all. This is normal since it has been set to `display: none` in CSS.

**Here is my question:** What is the solution to this? I want a situation whereby a user will still see the image even when JS is disabled in his browser. I don't want the image to slide in at this point, but I want it just to load and show like any other thing on the webpage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could detect whether JS is enabled (a few things come to mind like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), or simple `<noscript>` tags would probably do the trick... then add some additional CSS to show it again. It's only a quick and dirty answer, but it should do the trick:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #yourimage { display: block; }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: (+1) I had this problem before and did not know it so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could, by default, have the image displayed with `display:block;` and immediatley hide it with js. Don't use any libraries for this and put the js right after the `img`-tag in the code so that you won't have any delays.

This will:

- Show the image if JS is disabled, not hide the image since JS is disabled
- Hide the image if JS is disabled, your other image will be showed with your other JS-script.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use `<img>` tags to display all the images, and don't use `display: none`  so that if JS is disabled, it can be rendered in the browser.

Your JS should be used to control complex effects such as slide or hide images.